# Complicated if else logic in Java

Tags: java, logic, logical-operators, control-flow

I have **three** if statements:

`if (!(a == 0 && b == 0)) {...}`

`if (!(a == 0 && b != 0)) {...}`

`if (!(a != 0 && b != 0)) {...}`

I would like to combine them in one code block such as a method.

I don't want the other statements to run if one has run. There are workarounds if I want to avoid coming up with some good logic but I'd like to know if there is a beautiful way to write that.

Comment: it's a type. jsut `b` would be fine

Comment: Is the same logic executed if any of those `if` is met?

Comment: I suppose that is the case.

Comment: Well then, use `||` to join the evaluation of all your `if`s. Apart of that, I won't say this is complicated `if-else` logic.

Comment: Well somebody doing electronics said there is a way to make this more compact. I thought such a way existed.

Comment: There should be and you could do it after some boolean analysis. But more important: is this really necessary? Does this improves the code readability and performance or any other relevant factor for your app? If yes, then this is a great opportunity to improve this, probably with a code refactor. But if it is not, then just leave it as is.

Comment: You're missing a case - what if b and not a?

Comment: "I don't want the other statements to run if one has run"--then you'll have to rethink your logic, because there's some overlap.  For example, if `a` and `b` are both 0, the second and third statements will run in your example--but you say you only want one of them, so which one?

Comment: Hang on - you want to omit the other cases if the first one runs?  And to omit the third one if the second one runs?  So, basically put an `else` before the second and third ones?  In that case, the third one will never run!

Comment: The first think I'd do is use DeMorgan's Law.  Instead of `if (!(a == 0 && b == 0))`, write `if (a != 0 || b != 0)`.  This will make it clearer what's going on, especially if you've written it wrong... this will be true unless **both** `a` and `b` are 0.

Comment: If the logic executed in `{...}` is the same then the tests are completely redundant as the code will be executed if a == 0 or b == 0 or a != 0 or b != 0

Comment: @ajb The problem is I came up with each of the if statements on their own and at one point I had to combine them in a way that I described in the question.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (!(a == 0 && b b == 0)) {...}
```

truth table

```
a b r

z n T 
n n T 
z z F
n z T
```

for

```
if (!(a == 0 && b b != 0)) {...}
```

truth table

```
z n F
n n F 
z z T
n z T
```

for

```
if (!(a != 0 && b b != 0)) {...}
```

truth table

```
z n T
n n F
z z T
n z T
```

common case

```
n z T
```

so result that works on all 3 condition is

```
a != 0 && b == 0
```

note that: all 3 conditions are totally different, this will only work if you care to execute if

(first `&&` second `&&` third) is `true`

validate all case by yourself

<sub>(z = zero, n = non zero, a, b variables, r = result, T = true, F = false)</sub>

Comment: Nice explanation with truth tables :)

Comment: I think you've actually answered something quite different from what the OP intended to ask.  Either you've misunderstood the question, or I have.  In any case, I guess that's why it's been closed as unclear.

Comment: I think OP wants to make all three condition AND and derive a simpler condition

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to express this:

```
public int foo(boolean a, boolean b) {
  int result;
  if (a) {
    if (b) { result = 1; }
    else { result = 2; }
  else {
    if (b) { result = 3; }
    else { result = 4; }
  return result;   
}
```

(notice that this evaluates a and b once each, which is the minimum you can expect here)

To keep @DavidWallace happy, here's a translation to the particular form of the original question:

```
public int foo(int a, int b) {
  int result;
  if (a==0) {
    if (b==0) { result = 1; }  // or whatever should happen, not specified in the question
    else { result = 2; }
  else {
    if (b==0) { result = 3; }
    else { result = 4; }
  return result;   
}
```

Comment: But in the question, `a` and `b` are both `int`, not `boolean`.

Comment: @DavidWallace Jon refers to `boolean a` and `boolean b` parameters.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You what now?

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes, this is the general form of the solution - I imagine it's not too very difficult to translate it to any particular boolean expressions you might have in mind

Answer (score 1):

Just to re-word your question.  You say that if one block runs, the others shouldn't.  So when you wrote

```
if (!(a == 0 && b == 0)) {...}

if (!(a == 0 && b != 0)) {...}

if (!(a != 0 && b != 0)) {...}
```

You actually meant

```
if (!(a == 0 && b == 0)) { 
     // first ...
}
else if (!(a == 0 && b != 0)) {
     // second ...
}
else if (!(a != 0 && b != 0)) { 
     // third ...
}
```

But this is equivalent to

```
if (a != 0 || b != 0) { 
    // first ... 
}
else if (b == 0) { 
    // second ... 
}
```

Notice that the third `...` can never run, as I stated in my comment.